# JavaScript: how to calculate page traffic use?

Tags: javascript, traffic-measurement

Is it possible to calculate how much traffic my page uses? I know I can see it in Developer's Tools, but would it possible to get it in plain JavaScript?

[image]

I know I could read content-length header for AJAX requests, but this isn't something I'm looking for. I need to get all traffic that my page generates. Could put it into an iframe as well, it that helps.

Thanks.

Comment: This is done by the browser and I don't think it is possible to detect by the JavaScript. It would be out of scope. I guess?

Comment: Hope this will help : http://webcodingeasy.com/Javascript/Measure-page-loading-time-using-javascript-1

Comment: Perhaps you should explain *why* you need this, then alternatives may be suggested.

Comment: I need this for my clients. They want to know, how much traffic are their HTML5 ads consume.

Answer (score 4):

in chrome there is `window.performance.memory`

and read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigation_timing_API

you can use as solution but it is third party js :-

http://phantomjs.org/network-monitoring.html

Comment: not exactly what I was looking for, but yeah, close https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PerformanceResourceTiming/transferSize

Comment: What does Performance.memory have to do with the question of traffic use? It's about the JavaScript heap.